# Highcharts packed bubbles useHTML datalabels and add label on top of parent node

Tags: highcharts, label, packed

I create a packed bubbles with a useHTML option for the datalabels because I want these labels to be centered in each bubbles.

The result is fine, you can see it here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/1tk0m4qs/8/

My issue is about the parent node label, I would like it to be placed on top of each major bubble (as in the offical demo : https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series-packedbubble/packed-dashboard)

But as I need to set the useHTML flag on dataLabels, the label of parent node is placed in the center of each major bubble (which is not good).

If you set useHTML : false in my sample, the label of parent is correctly placed on top of the major bubbles but the labels of each bubbles is not centered anymore.

```
dataLabels: {
          useHTML: true,
```

How can I mix the two things (useHTML and place the parent label on top of bubble) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to enable `useHTML` to center the labels. It is enough to set `align: 'left'` and `'text-anchor': 'middle'` style. For example:

```
  plotOptions: {
    packedbubble: {
      ...,
      dataLabels: {
        ...,
        align: 'left',
        style: {
          'text-anchor': 'middle'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hdgL8yeb/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.packedbubble.dataLabels

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. I've 2 subsidiary questions about this chart : How can I change the style of the parent node label (on top of the node) to get a different style for node data labels and parent node data labels ? And how can I change the content of the parent node tooltip ?

Comment: Hi @vegaelce, You can use `parentNodeFormat` or `parentNodeFormatter`. For tooltip use `formatter` function and check `isParentNode` point's property. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/to5vcw4L/